# How to publish grails project to server (artifactory)?

Tags: grails, artifactory

I'm using intelliJ IDEA with grails project which i need to publish to my Artifactory server. 
I tried to make it by using this command line: 
**grails publish-plugin --noScm --repository=mediatorBaseRelease**

In my colleague PC it was working fine, but in my PC it showed me this
output:

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_35\bin\java
>   -Dgrails.home=C:\Dev\grails-2.2.4 -Dbase.dir=C:\Dev\madiator-base -Dtools.jar=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_35\lib\tools.jar -Dgroovy.starter.conf=C:\Dev\grails-2.2.4/conf/groovy-starter.conf -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:PermSize=256m -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit -Djline.WindowsTerminal.directConsole=false -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Dev\grails-2.2.4\lib\org.codehaus.groovy\groovy-all\jars\groovy-all-2.0.8.jar;C:\Dev\grails-2.2.4\dist\grails-bootstrap-2.2.4.jar
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter --main
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner --conf
>   C:\Dev\grails-2.2.4/conf/groovy-starter.conf publish-plugin --noScm
>   --repository=mediatorBase
>
> | Loading Grails 2.2.4  | Configuring classpath  | Running
>   pre-compiled script  | Script 'PublishPlugin' not found, did you mean:
>   1) ListPlugins_     2) ListPluginUpdates     3) PluginInfo_     4)
>   InstallPlugin     5) UninstallPlugin  Please make a selection or enter
>   Q to quit:

I wonder what do I need to do make this command run on my PC too. 
Do I miss some installations? grails version?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the 'refresh-dependencies' command solved this problem